# How to change the window size of the virtual terminal in termux

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

ccmake ../src
Window is too small. A size of at least 65 x 6 is required to run ccmake

How to resolve this

Comment: I am working on termux and getting this error . how to change the #columns *#rows

Comment: Increase the size of your window above the mentioned minimum size.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the Terminal window size to some preset values:

Press the menu button in the top-right corner of the window and select Advanced.

Choose one of the following options:

80×24

80×43

132×24

132×43

If you require custom size Terminal windows, you can also set the default window size according to your requirements:

Press the menu button in the top-right corner of the window and select Preferences.

In the sidebar, select your current profile in the Profiles section.

Select Text.

Set Initial terminal size by typing the desired number of columns and rows in the corresponding input boxes. You can also click + to increase or - to decrease the size.

Comment: there is no menu button, in fact there is no gui in termux. please help me with the commands only. it will be great for me.

Comment: Such option exists in Linux terminal programs, but not in `termux`